# crashed when click blue or red cell

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

During using SWReveallViewController to get sliding-out menu like Facebook app, download from github, [John-Lluch / SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), referring to

[SWRevealViewController / RevealControllerStoryboardExample /](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerStoryboardExample/RevealControllerStoryboardExample)

I only just changed code for `ViewDidLoad` in `colorViewController.m` from

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

to

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

then run it, when rear view revealed and blue cell clicked, it crashed, red cell as well.

debug said:

```
RevealControllerStoryboardExample[2244:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

What happened? I didn't touch any other in this sample but change a little as above. My intention is to be able to pan any place in the view, not only panning on navigation bar.

Could anyone help me fix the issue?

Comment: To clarify: It worked before this change?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `self.revealViewController` is nil…  The reason that it didn't crash before is that `self.navigationController` is *also* nil, so the message the original code tries to send (which would normally throw the same nil argument exception) is never actually sent.

Comment: thanks @AaronGolden ! so.....how can I do to fix its nil......? – iOS.dev just now edit

Comment: My instinct is to not bother trying to fix this.  I mean, why do you even want to use this project?  If even the minimal demo projects have weird bugs imagine the headaches you're going to have using the library in a non-trivial way!

Comment: Actually, I just use its original .h and .m for realizing sliding-out in my own project by understanding some key snippet for reference, not use this demo's whole function.

In my own app, I hope swiping any place in the view to slide main menu out, not only on navigation bar. 

So I changed the method to self.view, but crashed......

Answer (score 0):

For others reading this to get unstuck:

If you're implementing SWRevealViewController + Storyboards and if you're properly selecting the custom "reveal view controller" segue, then you must also call the SWRevealViewControllerSegue class from your prepareForSegue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]]) {

        SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvcs = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        SWRevealViewController* rvc = self.revealViewController;

        rvcs.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

        UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];

        [rvc setFrontViewController:nc animated:YES];

       };
    }
}
```